# What is the safe way to load commands from a set of files that is not static?

Tags: node.js

I am looping through the files in my Commands folder and loading them using require.

ESLint tells me this is wrong. What is the safe way to load commands from a set of files that is not static?

[image: node.js code snippet]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  It sounds like you already know the reason for the warning and you want to dynamically load modules who's name is not predefined.  So, you make sure the strings you construct are safe and you disable the warning.  What else are you asking here?  You could engineer your own code loader if you want, but that seems like it has no less vulnerabilities and is just a lot more work so not really a point to that.

Answer (score 0):

The warning exists for security reasons. It is rare that you need to dynamically require files. Quote from the [documentation](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/blob/master/README.md):

> `detect-non-literal-require`
>
> Detects require(variable), which might allow an attacker to load and run arbitrary code, or access arbitrary files on disk.
>
> More information: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

If you know that in your code it is safe, I see no better way then to suppress the warning for the next line.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was aware of the reason for the warning. I already know I can require each command file I load, but I was wanting to not have to rebuild each time I load a new command.